# Ho do I get value from State in PyMonad library?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm learning PyMonad trying to scratch the surface of the functional programming. I have this code:

```
from pymonad.tools import curry
from pymonad.state import State

user_init = {'items': [], 'money': 2000}

items = {'apples': 70,
         'wine': 300,
         'milk': 80,
         'chips': 100
         }

user_state = State(user_init['items'], user_init['money'])


@curry(2)
def buy(item, user_items):
    @State
    def count_computation(old_count):
        return user_items.append(item), old_count - items[item]
    return count_computation

finale = user_state.then(buy('wine')).then(buy('apples')).then(buy('chips')).then(buy('chips')).then(buy('milk'))
```

How do I get state and value from `finale` or `user_state`?